# What are some examples of text to use for common comments?

Tags: discussion, comments

There are many comments I find myself leaving often. Probably the most common is a reminder to back up answers, but "be nice", "one question per question", and "visit the help page" all come up frequently too.

On other stacks, I have observed something like standard comments that get left in these situations. They aren't formal, just nice copy that is being recycled.

I wanted to open up a space where we can develop our own common comments in the hopes of improving the quality of our interactions with users.

I will post my own below to get things started. Let's try to keep one "comment" per answer so users will know what they are upvoting/downvoting/suggesting edits too.

Comment: If you include links or markup in your comment, please also post the source code formatted as source code, so people can simply copy-paste. [Here is an analogous thread at Meta.CrossValidated](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2468/1352), where we do this.

Answer (score 3):

> Comments are for [clarifying content](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment), not posting small or incomplete answers. Please use answer posts to submit answers instead.

```
Comments are for
[clarifying content](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment),
not posting small or incomplete answers. Please use answer posts to submit answers instead.
```

Answer (score 2):

> Questions here have specific factual answers. Your question might be better suited to a chat room or a traditional forum, as you'll get more helpful feedback on a site intended for open-ended discussion.

Answer (score -1):

> Can you provide a link to further reading?

The intent is something to point out that sources would help while being non-confrontational.

Comment: Would it be more educational to also link to the back-it up post on meta?

Comment: Certainly pointing users to existing discussions on meta is better than recreating them in comments, but I would suggest not leading with it is less confrontational or dismissive and more engaging.